# ShellExecuteEx() force window to top z order

Tags: c, winapi, window

I looking for a method for forcing windows to set the program I launch with *ShellExecuteEx()* in first in z order.

The base of the problem is an issue with a machine (only one) and Google Chrome
When I launch Chrome from *ShellExecuteEx()* with this parameters :

> http://www.google.fr --kiosk --fast-start --chrome-frame

It doesn't display the window, but I see the Chrome icon flashing in the bar.

I've tried to force the window by using *EnumWindows()* and *BringWindowToTop()* then *SetWindowPos()* with *HWND_TOPMOST* flag but this doesn't work for all programs I've tried.

Actualy I get a *HWND* by comparing pids

```
BOOL CALLBACK   SetWindowToTopFromhProcess(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HANDLE      hProcess = (HANDLE)lParam;
    DWORD       win_pid = 0;
    DWORD       pid = 0;
    char        buf[512];

    pid = GetProcessId(hProcess);
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &win_pid);
    if (pid == win_pid && pid != 0 && win_pid != 0)
    {
        //SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
        BringWindowToTop(hwnd);

        memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
        GetWindowText(hwnd, buf, sizeof(buf));
        printf("%s\n", buf);

        return (FALSE);
    }
    return (TRUE);
}

int                     my_function()
{
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO    ExecuteInfo;

    ...
    ExecuteInfo.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    ...
    if (ShellExecuteEx(&ExecuteInfo))
        EnumWindows(SetWindowToTopFromhProcess, (LPARAM)ExecuteInfo.hProcess);
    ...
}
```

By the way, I've realized that the window handle I getting from the pid is not always the handle I want. For example with mspaint.exe the window name I retrieve is "GDI+ Window", so it's not the good window because it's not the good pid.

I've also tried a lot of nShow flags in the *SHELLEXECUTEINFO* structure who doesn't work.

So how to get the good window handle ? Is there another way to force the program I run to display its main window?
Or any idea ?

Comment: There is no single answer for all programs. Pick an app. Just one.

Comment: Seriously ?? What a cruel world... So Google Chrome...

Comment: This is an XY question.  There's something wrong with that machine, reformat its hard drive so it can't make anybody else's life miserable.

Comment: You really think there is something wrong with that machine or it's a joke ? For the XY question, it would be better if I repost the question but from another angle or David Heffernan has already said everything?

Comment: Is your application launching Chrome foreground when it calls `ShellExecuteEx`?

Comment: Yes I think, in the _SHELLEXECUTEINFO_ struct I set _lpVerb_ to "open" and _nShow_ to SW_SHOWNORMAL.

Comment: If you want to add an answer to your own question you can. But do it as an answer rather than an edit to your question.

Comment: [This Answer][1] was very helpful for me.  
Now it's work fine.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166178/shell-execute-bring-window-to-front

Comment: **Trivial answer converted to comment** That is what I wanted to do but I get this message... Is my answer too short ?